# When is it a maven project?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

When I download the .zip-file from start.spring.io, I download a maven-project, right?

Is it a maven-project, as soon as I use maven to manage my dependencies? Or is a maven-project something seperate, which I include into my project?

Comment: why the downvote? I was just unshure about it because many have used that term and I couldn't find when a project is actually a maven-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities: 
1. To download a Maven Project from start.spring.io using Spring Initialzr.
2. To download a Gradle Project from start.spring.io using Spring Initialzr.

The project that you download from start.spring.io, in your case it's a Maven Project with all the selected dependencies already. You can recognize a Maven Project about pom.xml file where all the dependencies are included. So, all you must do after downloading the zip file from start.spring.io is to unzip the archive and after that to import the maven project (chosing the pom.xml file) in you IDE.

Comment: So, as soon as there is a pom.xml file in my project, it is called a maven project.

Comment: I can choose spring-data-jpa and spring-data-jdbc and spring-data-HSQLDB.
But when using spring-boot-starter, doesn't that include multiple things?

Comment: Yes, spring initialzr include in pom.xml all selected dependencies

Comment: But I mean when I choose to use spring-boot-starter-HSQLDB, isn't JPA and JDBC included?

Comment: You can look inside the maven dependencies in your IDE and see what jars are there.